# react hooks how to combine arrays

Tags: reactjs, api, react-hooks

I fetch two API calls

````
"people": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "person": "A",
      "departmentId": 1,
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "person": "B",
      "departmentId": 2,
    }]    ```

    and second is with departments 

    ```  
    "departments": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "departmentName": "services"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "departmentName": "services2"
    }]
````

I display people list with .map function and I would like to show the departments not as numbers but as department names. I use react hooks,
Thank you for help

Comment: You can create a dictionary / map of departments as soon as you receive it, e.g. `departments: {1: 'Dept 1', 2: 'Some other dept'}`.

Comment: probably my question is not clear :/ 
how I will combine both results to have name of the department instead of the number?
so if departmentId is 2 it will show sevice2

Comment: By creating a *map* as I explained above, you can just do: `{people.map(p => <div>{p.person}, {departmentMap[p.departmentId]}</div>)}` So, time complexity will get reduced.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for combination of [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) array methods:

```js
people = [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "person": "A",
      "departmentId": 1,
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "person": "B",
      "departmentId": 2,
    }];


departments = [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "departmentName": "services"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "departmentName": "services2"
    }];
    
const getDepartmentName = (id) => departments.find(dep => dep.id === id).departmentName;

const peopleWithDepartments = people.map(p => ({...p, departmentName: getDepartmentName(p.departmentId)}));

console.log(peopleWithDepartments);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you do this on the api side otherwise this is a small script that does the job;

```
people.map(person => {
    return `${person.person} works at ${departments.find(department => department.id == person.departmentId)?.departmentName}`
})
```